# When I write page name in action attribute the file image does not upload

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I write page name in action attribute the file image does not upload. If i write `"#"` in action page the image upload to target folder.
Please check the coding and mention mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">
<input type="file" name="imageupload" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="frmsubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
include 'includes/dbconnection.php';
if(isset($_POST['frmsubmit'])){
$image_name = $_FILES['imageupload']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['imageupload']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['imageupload']['size'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['imageupload']['tmp_name'];
$target_dir = "dp/";
$path = $target_dir . $image_name;
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $path);
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["imageupload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded."; }?>
```

Comment: What are you putting in the `action=""` attribute

Comment: try this `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`

Comment: when i putted formsubmit.php the the image dont upload to dp folder

Comment: but dear i want that after submitting the image i want to go on another page

Comment: if i put 'action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  will not go to another page'

Comment: Then use a redirect from PHP `header('Location: otherform.php');`

Comment: header('Location: otherform.php'); then where i write ??

Comment: write it after `move _uploaded_file();`

Comment: ohhh thanks wow!!!

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Goody\submitad.php:155) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Goody\submitad.php on line 187

Comment: now i am getting this warning on submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In form's action you can use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. Then it will send the files to same script. If you are using same php script to upload the file then it is good. I have modified you code please have a look at that

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<input type="file" name="imageupload" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="frmsubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
include 'includes/dbconnection.php';
if(isset($_POST['frmsubmit'])){
$image_name = $_FILES['imageupload']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['imageupload']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['imageupload']['size'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['imageupload']['tmp_name'];
$target_dir = "dp/";
$path = $target_dir . $image_name;
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $path);
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["imageupload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded."; }?>
```

Then after successful file upload you can use `header("Location")`  to transfer user to any page.

Comment: I would recommend putting the php code **above** the form, as if the OP tried to use `header("Location...")` it would result in a `Headers already sent`error.

Comment: You can write the header("Location") after move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $path).

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Goody\submitad.php:155) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Goody\submitad.php on line 187

Comment: If you can show the final code which is giving the issue then its solution can be given. Please paste the final code which is giving the issue.